# Is it possible to get an email feed that gives a random selection of answers across selected networks?

Tags: feature-request, email-notification

I often find myself reading the answers to questions from different networks as I find some of answers interesting.  Is it possible to have a similar email feed?

Answer (score 2):

The Hot Network Questions have [an RSS feed](https://stackexchange.com/feeds/questions). You could use that on one of several RSS-to-email services (I wrote my own script for that, so I can't recommend one).